# What is the procedure for installing graylog 2.x on windows..?

Tags: windows, graylog2, graylog

I have requirement to setup graylog and elasticsearch on windows.

Version: 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Running Graylog on Windows is not supported, see [System Requirements](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/installation.html#system-requirements).

If you absolutely *have* to run Graylog on a Windows-based system, you have to use the virtual appliance (OVA) and run it in HyperV/VMWare/VirtualBox.

See [Virtual Machine Appliances](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/installation/virtual_machine_appliances.html) for details.