# net core app crash on windows when Gelf using

Tags: .net-core, nlog, gelf

I have a .net core application that runs successfully in production.
I use Nlog to write to the log, it writes to debug.txt and graylog.
It works successfully on k8s.
However, when I try to debug locally on Windows 10, if graylog is enabled, the application crashes with the following error.
If graylog is disabled, then everything is fine.
here is part of nlog.config

```
        <target xsi:type="Gelf" name="graylog" endpoint="udp://graylogHost" facility="netcore"
                SendLastFormatParameter="true" gelfVersion="1.1">
            <parameter name="assembly" layout="${appdomain:format={1\}:cached=True}" />
            <parameter name="log-level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
            <parameter name="callsite"
                       layout="${callsite:className=True:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True}" />
            <parameter name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
            <!--<parameter name="hostname" layout="${right:inner=${hostname}:length=5}"/>-->
            <parameter name="hostname" layout="${hostname}" />
            <parameter name="activityId"
                       layout="${activityid:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier:whenEmpty=${activity:property=TraceId}}}" />
            <parameter name="hierarchicalId"
                       layout="${activity:property=Id}" />
            <parameter name="spanId"
                       layout="${activity:property=SpanId}" />
            <parameter name="parentId"
                       layout="${activity:property=ParentId}" />
            <parameter name="traceId"
                       layout="${activity:property=TraceId}" />
        </target>
```

And here is error

```
type hereStack overflow.
Repeat 12112 times:
--------------------------------
   at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.Equals(System.Object)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalModuleBuilder.Equals(System.Object)
--------------------------------
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].IndexOf(System.__Canon[], System.__Canon, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Array.IndexOf[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon[], System.__Canon, Int32, Int32)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Object, System.Type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObjectInternal(System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer)
   at NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf.GelfConverter.AddAdditionalField(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.Object,System.Object>)
   at NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf.GelfConverter.GetGelfJson(NLog.LogEventInfo, System.String, System.String)
   at NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf.GelfTarget.Write(NLog.LogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo>)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo>)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvents(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo>)
   at NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.WriteLogEventsToTarget(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo>, System.String)
   at NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.WriteLogEventsInQueue(Int32, System.String)
   at NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

I updated Nlog, I updated Gelf. I removed Newtonsoft from app, but nothing helped.
I will be glad to any ideas: why this code work on K8s and not work on Win10

Comment: "why this code work on ...."  You did not show any code ?

Comment: "Windows" i snot supported?  (see: [Running Graylog on Windows is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47349490/724039)) and https://go2docs.graylog.org/5-2/downloading_and_installing_graylog/installing_graylog.html?tocpath=Downloading%20and%20Installing%20Graylog%7CInstalling%20Graylog%7C_____0#SystemRequirements

Comment: Luuk, Thank you for participating. Windows is supported. What additional details of code you are need?

Comment: Graylog is working in another host with linux. I have problem only when enable Gelf locally

Comment: Why does it not mention "Windows", after "The Graylog server application is compatible with the following operating systems:"  ([here](https://go2docs.graylog.org/5-2/downloading_and_installing_graylog/installing_graylog.html?tocpath=Downloading%20and%20Installing%20Graylog%7CInstalling%20Graylog%7C_____0#SystemRequirements:~:text=The%20Graylog%20server%20application%20is%20compatible%20with%20the%20following%20operating%20systems%3A))  ??

Comment: Graylog is working in another host with linux. I have problem only when enable Gelf locally to write data on this host

Answer (score 0):

You can try and upgrade to the latest [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)-nuget-package (Adding it as explicit dependency for your application-project). Maybe they have changed the default JSON-serializer-settings to prevent StackOverflow.

Alternative you can stop using [NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf), and instead use NLog NetworkTarget together with [NLog.GelfLayout](https://github.com/farzadpanahi/NLog.GelfLayout) (Though it doesn't support `SendLastFormatParameter="true"`).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77379746/193178